# C# driver Mongo: Get all existing field types

Tags: c#, mongodb, types, field, driver

I'm using C# driver 2.0. I want to add fields in my collection. How can I get all the MongoTypes in ObservableCollection? o, my user could input new field name, choose field type - and here we are.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for your requirements?

```
public ObservableCollection<BsonType> GetFieldTypes(IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> collection)
{
    ObservableCollection<BsonType> fieldTypes = new ObservableCollection<BsonType>();

    var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Exists("_id", true);
    var findTask = collection.Find<BsonDocument>(filter).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    findTask.Wait();

    findTask.Result.Elements.Select(e => e.Value.BsonType).ToList().ForEach(b => fieldTypes.Add(b));
    return fieldTypes;
}
```

If you need all the types in your MongoDB, I think following code would work.

```
public ObservableCollection<BsonType> GetAllFieldTypes(MongoClient client)
{
    var taskListDB = client.ListDatabasesAsync();
    taskListDB.Wait();
    ObservableCollection<BsonType> allfieldTypes = new ObservableCollection<BsonType>();
    bool end = false;
    do
    {
        var taskMoveNext = taskListDB.Result.MoveNextAsync();
        taskMoveNext.Wait();

        allfieldTypes.AsEnumerable<BsonType>().ToList().AddRange(taskListDB.Result.Current.FirstOrDefault().Elements.Select(e => e.Value.BsonType).ToList());

        end = taskMoveNext.Result;
    } while (end);

    return allfieldTypes;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I don't understand your code. I need all predefined field types in MongoDb. For now - I created "technical" collection with one document, which containts fileds with various types. But it doesn't seem to me like a right decision. So, I need collection not with field names, but field types.

Comment: Okay, I mistook something. 
I've changed my answer to get all the field types in ObservableCollection. I think you might want to use BsonType list.

Comment: Does it get all existing field types in MongoDb or only that from my collection?

Comment: You can get types only from the collection assigned as the parameter "collection".

Comment: So, there're no way to get all MongoTypes? I only need to create a document with fields of every MongoType? just to be sure. Thanks!

Comment: I've edited my answer so that you can get all the types in your MongoDB. If you just need all the types in MongoDB, MongoDB.Bson.BsonType is enum for all the predefined types in every MongoDB.